# Intersection Area of Two Shapefiles - Python

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two shapefiles in python and I would like to find the area of all spaces they overlap.

I can use sjoin from geopandas to get areas where they join, but for locations where there are multiple overlaps I would like to only keep the one with the largest area.

```
municipality = gpd.read_file(muni_file)
soil_type = gpp.read_file(soil)
combined = gpd.sjoin(municipality,soil_type,how="left",op="intersects")
```

With OGR I can get the area of a polygon as below

```
from osgeo import ogr

wkt = "POLYGON ((1162440.5712740074 672081.4332727483, 1162440.5712740074 647105.5431482664, 1195279.2416228633 647105.5431482664, 1195279.2416228633 672081.4332727483, 1162440.5712740074 672081.4332727483))"
poly = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
```

So I am wondering if there is a way to take my combined shapefile and have the area where the two intersect so that I only keep the maximum one for each municipality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe you can loop thru combined via apply and get the size of each of the intersections.

start with reindex of combined as I'm assuming they're are duplicates from sjoin()

```
combined = combined.reset_index()
```

Then define a helper function (get_size_of_intersection) then we'll loop thru combined and apply get_size_of_intersection() and create a new series called intersection_size

some notes:

-combined will have the geometry of municipality

-combined will have a column/series called index_right which will be the index of soil_type

-since these are shapely objects we're dealing with we can leverage intersection() and the area property

```
def get_size_of_intersection(row, soil_type):
    return row['geometry'].intersection(soil_type['geometry'].iloc[int(row['index_right'])]).area

combined['intersection_size'] = combined.apply(lambda row : 
                                       get_size_of_intersection(row, soil_type), axis=1)
```

We'll create another series called max_intersection_size. Here I'm assuming municipality has some sort of 'name' series that we can group on and apply max()

```
combined['max_intersection_size'] = combined.groupby('name')['intersection_size'].transform(max)
```

Then using boolean indexing we get our desired data

(ie where intersection_size equals max_intersection_size)

```
filter = combined['intersection_size'] == combined['max_intersection_size']
combined[filter]
```